# SwinjectStoryboard container resolves different objects (instances)

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swinject

I've tried Swinject(SwinjectStoryboard) and got a problem. Please help me.

```
extension SwinjectStoryboard {

   @objc class func setup() {
      defaultContainer.register(SomeClass.self) { _ in
            SomeClass()
      }

      defaultContainer.storyboardInitCompleted(FirstViewController.self) { r, c in
           c.someClass = r.resolve(SomeClass.self)
      }

      defaultContainer.storyboardInitCompleted(SecondViewController.self) { r, c in
           c.someClass = r.resolve(SomeClass.self)
      }
   }
}
```

After adding dependencies I have different objects (instances) of SomeClass in FirstViewController and SecondViewController.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the registration of `SomeClass` to:

```
defaultContainer.register(SomeClass.self) { _ in SomeClass() }
    .inObjectScope(.container)
```

You can learn more about the object scopes in [Swinject docs](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/ObjectScopes.md).